# how to write a regular expression for the following scenario?

Tags: python, regex

I like to write a regular expression for the following scenario

Regex:?

**example 1**

input:

```
I got good morning message
```

output:

```
good morning
```

**example 2**

input

```
good morning message
```

output

```
good morning
```

**example 3**

input:

```
my friend got thank you message from xyz
```

output:

```
thank you
```

The output should contain the message by neglecting other details like `i got`, `message`, `my friend got`. The message can be anything not only `good morning`, `thank you`.

Comment: It can be done using `in` operator why you want to complicate things by using `regex`?

Comment: Sounds like you are after NLP. If so try NLTK or Spacy.

Comment: no actually i have to do with regex only...

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get the string between the got and message keywords or match from the beginning of the string if there is no got in it, then you can use the following code:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('(?:.*got )?(?(1)got |)(.*) message')
pattern.search('my friend got thank you message from xyz').group(1)
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly you want to get the message between got and message, or from the start of the string if you can't find got?

In that case you could use:

```
[^|got ](.*) message
```

Then you could extract the capture group by doing \1 (might vary a little on the program or language).